# « Stocker » contre « emmagasiner »

Tags: usage, synonymes

Parlant de l'énergie :

> Lorsqu'un objet reçoit un joule de l'énergie, il peut l'*emmagasiner*/le *stocker*, soit le fournir à l'extérieur ;  mais en aucun cas il ne peut le détruire.

Quel verbe est le plus adéquat dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stocker ou emmagasiner sont équivalents ici.

--- hors sujet ---

En revanche, le première partie de la phrase est incorrecte. *Un joule de l'énergie* n'a pas de sens, ce pourrait être *un joule d'énergie* mais vu qu'un joule est forcément de l'énergie, il est probablement inutile de le préciser.

D'autre part, préciser ***un*** joule apporte une précision inopportune. Elle pourrait laisser entendre que l'affirmation n'est peut-être pas vérifiée s'il s'agit de dix joules, un kJ, un millijoule...

On pourrait donc dire

> Lorsqu'un objet reçoit de l'énergie, il peut soit l'emmagasiner, soit la rediffuser, mais en aucun cas il ne peut la détruire.

Ceci permet aussi de traiter le cas où l'énergie est partiellement absorbée.

Note: il manquait aussi le premier *soit* à la phrase proposée (il peut **soit** l'emmagasiner, soit...)

Answer (score 1):

Les deux termes sont à peu près équivalents ; le second peut être légèrement préférable, comme le premier a des connotations qui le rapprochent du mot « réserve » mais il me semble que cela ne vaille pas une remarque ; par exemple « avoir quelque chose en stock » signifie qu'il y a une réserve de cette chose mais « avoir quelque chose en magasin » peut signifier seulement que cette chose est disponible dans le magasin, sans qu'il en existe une réserve trop importante. On peut dire par exemple « le foie emmagasine de la vitamine D » ou « le foie stocke de la vitamine D » de façon tout à fait équivalente. Il n'y a pas de problème dans le contexte physique de l'absorption d'énergie.

Answer (score 1):

La bonne réponse dépend comme toujours du contexte.
Les réponses précédentes me semblent tout à fait  raisonnables, mais en passant je ne suis pas sûr  que "stocker" soit vraiment du français.
En agriculture on dirait "engranger", en physique,  on peut opter pour votre emmagasiner" ou mieux "accumuler".

Une autre forumuation plus précise, si l'énergie est changée de nature  et spécialement est transformée  en chaleur,  on peut dire que "l'énergie est dissipée".

Comment: Merci de votre réponse !

Comment: « Stocker » est bien du français ; c'est un mot qui vient de l'anglais mais il y a plus de cent années et on l'utilise beaucoup ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/stocker)).